# Estimating gyroscope bias for attitude IMU sensor fusion with an unscented Kalman filter

Tags: kalman-filter, sensor-fusion, estimation, drone

I'm trying to use a UKF as the attitude estimator for a drone with just a gyroscope and accelerometer as sensors. So far, it's going well and after some tuning appears to perform basically as well as a Madgwick filter in simulated testing. However, when the drone is stationary on the ground, the UKF accumulates a much greater error in its attitude estimate than the Madgwick filter which seems to be caused by gyro bias (note that the bias of the simulated gyro is not even that large and a dead-reckoning estimator only accumulates about a 10 degree error after 10 seconds).

All this has led me to try adding gyro bias to the state vector of the UKF which seems like a common strategy in Kalman filtering land for mitigating sensor bias. Unfortunately, adding this term to the state and incorporating it in the gyro sensor model for the update step has completely broken the UKF making its attitude estimate seem basically random. It seems to come up with unrealistically large estimates of the bias that change very quickly which is obviously not correct.

It feels like adding this bias to the state makes it hard for the UKF to differentiate how much of a measurement should count as bias vs what is actually real. Anyway, what can I try to fix this? Is there some trick to tuning the process/measurement model covariances or is this simply a case of there not being enough information available to estimate the gyro bias? I suspect I'm just doing something wrong as I would expect a UKF to outperform Madgwick when set up correctly.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics,* brennanenanen. How did you augment the state matrix to include the gyro bias? How did you select the weight/noise matrices and what happens when you adjust those values? Also, I'm curious why you're expecting the UKF to outperform the Madgwick filter; [his publication](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5975346) states, "Results indicate the algorithm achieves levels of accuracy matching that of the Kalman based algorithm."

Comment: What process noise covariance have you tried to use and have you tried to lower the entries associated with bias states by a significant amount?

Comment: Sorry for this basic question, at what step are the accelerometer's and gyroscope's 6 sensors calibrated? I think I missed something. (Or see something missing.)

Comment: @Chuck I'm representing the gyro bias as a 3d vector in the state (it just gets added to the gyro measurement in the measurement model). Your point on Madgwick performance is fair, that last sentence in my post is probably not valid. That being said, I would still expect there to be some way to make the UKF more accurate when the drone is stationary (and to reject the gyro bias better).

Comment: As for covariance @fibonatic, I have tried a lot of fiddling. The closest thing to kinda working was as you suggested - very low covariance for the bias terms in the process noise. For reference, currently I have the measurement noise of the gyro a bit lower than that of the accelerometer which seems to work well when the state is just attitude.

Comment: @st2000 I don't really want to rely on hard calibration of the sensors as ideally, I would like the system to be able to dynamically estimate the sensor 'calibration' (i.e. the gyro bias) as it changes over longer periods of time. Besides, my whole issue at the moment is that Madgwick seems to do a fine job of rejecting the gyro bias when stationary but the UKF does not.

Comment: Huh. Having spent some more time playing around with different parameters and configurations, I've just found that setting the gyro bias's initial covariance very low and its process noise all the way to zero is giving much better results (like often better than Madgwick). For whatever reason, setting the process noise to even a very small number just wasn't enough and the bias covariance would keep growing over time. When the process noise is 0, the covariance of the bias never changes which seems to be working in this case. I need to investigate a little more but I might mark this as solved.